# Print Value of an Array inside an Array

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

```
Array ( 
    [trailer_data] => Array () 
    [constructiondata] => Array () 
    [car_data] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [body] => "Hatchback" 
            [make] => "Alfa Romeo" 
            [year] => 1978 
            [model] => "Alfetta" 
            [description] => "First Clone" 
            [operable] => "Operable" 
            [convertible] => "Convertible" 
            [modified] => "Modified" 
            [average_dimension] => "1267mm x 1620mm x 4024mm" 
            [average_weight] => "915kg" 
         )
    ) 
    [commercial_data] => Array () 
    [bike_data] => Array () 
    [farm_data] => Array () 
    [rc_data] => Array () 
    [atv_data] => Array () 
)

Array ( [trailer_data] => Array ( ) [constructiondata] => Array ( ) [car_data] => Array ( ) [commercial_data] => Array ( ) [bike_data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [body] => Moped [make] => dds [year] => sdsd [model] => sdsd [description] => sdsd [operable] => Operable [convertible] => Convertible [modified] => Modified [trike] => Not Trike [average_dimension] => [average_weight] => ) ) [farm_data] => Array ( ) [rc_data] => Array ( ) [atv_data] => Array ( ) )
```

**I just want to check empty and print arrays which is not empty !
How can I do it in Laravel blade ?**

*thank you*

Comment: can you show blade template code

Comment: Either process your data in a controller, or use `@if` inside a loop.

Comment: @JohnLobo I have updated the question , can you please check ?

Comment: @PrasadChathuranga.check my answer

Comment: Check `array_filter` function and pass to view what is filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for empty array in if condition

```
@foreach($bike  as $key=>$value)
 
    @if(is_array($value)&&count($value))
        @foreach($value as $subkey=>$subvalue)
        {{$subvalue['body']}}
        @endforeach
    @endif
 
 @endforeach
```

**Updated**

```
 @foreach($bike  as $key=>$value)
 
    @if(is_array($value)&&count($value))
        @foreach($value as $subkey=>$subvalue)
                @if(is_array($subvalue)&&count($subvalue))
                
                    @foreach($subvalue as $individualKey=>$individualValue)
                    
                        if(!empty($individualValue))
                            
                            {{$individualValue}}
                        
                        @endif
                        
                    @endforeach
                
                @endif
        
        
        @endforeach
    @endif
 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: but how can I check and print values if the values are different from each arrays ?

Comment: any sample data ?so  ican check what you are looking for

Comment: @PrasadChathuranga.if its helped dont forget to accept answer

Comment: but the values in the arrays are not the same, So how can I check one by one ?

Comment: I have updated the question with different array values, can you please check ?

Comment: it's working fine for car and bike, but not for others

Comment: i think its not structured array.you should create array such that it should be predicatable or else you need to check each time what type of value is

Comment: yeah I see , really thank you for the answer and your time ! good luck for your future works !! stay safe !!!

Comment: for you too .:)

Answer (score 0):

user foreach for iterata array and check every element if is em

```
@foreach($array as $a)
    @if($a)
        {{$a['index']}}
    @endif    
@endforeach
```